# C# how to achieve 'group by' 'left join' and list inside a list selection in linq

Tags: c#, list, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
var products = from P in product.GetAllAsync().Result
                           join PV in 
_repositoryVariation.GetAllAsync().Result on P.Id equals PV.ProductId
                           into PVLJ
                           from PV in PVLJ.DefaultIfEmpty()

                           select new ProductwithVarientsGroupDto
                           {
                               Label = P.ProductName,
                               ProductId = P.Id,
                               Items = new List<ProdcutVariantsdto>() { new ProdcutVariantsdto { Label = P.ProductName.ToString() + (PV == null ? "" : " (" + PV?.VariantName.ToString() + ")"), ProductId = P.Id, ProdVariantId = PV?.Id > 0 ? PV?.Id : 0 } }
                                 //here i need to add multiple variant records to Items, now it 
                                  // showing each item as a separate row data 
                           };
            var result = products.ToList();
            return result;
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `await`?

Comment: This isn't EF Core code. There's no `GetAllAsync()` in EF Core - it's not needed. What this seems to be doing is load all products in memory and try to join and filter them afterwards. EF Core doesn't need those JOINs either, they're automatically generated as needed from the entities' relations and DbContext configuration

Comment: so what's your point on to fix that..

Comment: Looks like you used the "generic" repository **anti**pattern, with an implementation that returns *all* results in `GetAll`. It would be *far* easier and faster to use EF Core properly. The repository antipattern is a *low level* construct. An ORM is a *higher-level* abstraction. By putting it on top of EF Core you've broken it without gaining any benefits

Comment: How to fix that: Remove the repository completely. Use proper entities and relations and let EF Core create the joins. If `Product` has a property called `Variations`, EF Core will automatically load all related `Variations`. A simple `var products=(from product in _context.Products select new MyDTO { Label=product.Name, Items=product.Variations}).ToList()` would work just fine. You could add extra operations to `product.Variations` to extract specific fields only

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  The above query is work just fine.. what i need to fix is on that selection i just comment out something that what i need to fix..

Comment: It isn't working **at all**. You're loading **all** products and **all** variants from the database in memory, then trying to join without benefit of indexing. This is extremely slow and due to locking while reading from the database, will block any other code that tries to insert or update records in that table. This will seriously harm scaleability in any except the smallest applications

Comment: It's also not needed - if you use EF Core properly all the complexity vanishes. I only had to write two lines to retrieve nested products and variants, *without* loading any unwanted data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will work. After you left joined the data, just switch to client-evaluation (using `AsEnumerable()` or `ToList()`) and do the actual grouping with Linq. EF Core will not be able to do a Linq style grouping on its own and the data is being retrieved anyway, so there is no downside doing it client-side:

```cs
var products = (from p in context.Products
    join v in
        context.ProductVariations on p.Id equals v.ProductId
        into g
    from v in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {product = p, variation = v})
    .AsEnumerable() // <-- switch to client-evaluation
    .GroupBy(g => g.product, g => g.variation)
    .Select(g => new ProductwithVarientsGroupDto
    {
        Label = g.Key.ProductName,
        ProductId = g.Key.Id,
        Items = g.Select(v => new ProdcutVariantsdto()
        {
            Label = g.Key.ProductName + (v == null
                ? ""
                : " (" + v.VariantName.ToString() + ")"),
            ProductId = g.Key.Id,
            ProdVariantId = v.Id > 0
                ? v.Id
                : 0
        }).ToList()
    });
```

As @PanagiotisKanavos already mentioned in the comments, your original code first retrieves all entities from the database and then executes your query on them in memory. If you want to keep doing that, just replace `context.Products` with `product.GetAllAsync().Result` and `context.ProductVariations` with `_repositoryVariation.GetAllAsync().Result`. You could then also drop the `AsEnumerable()`, because you are already processing the query client-side.

---

Here is the fully working sample console project I used for testing:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductVariation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string VariantName { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class ProductwithVarientsGroupDto
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public List<ProdcutVariantsdto> Items = new List<ProdcutVariantsdto>();
    }
    
    public class ProdcutVariantsdto
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int? ProdVariantId { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductVariation> ProductVariations { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(
                    @"Data Source=.\MSSQL14;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=So63031344")
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasData(
                new Product {Id = 1, ProductName = "Car"},
                new Product {Id = 2, ProductName = "Bus"});

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductVariation>().HasData(
                new ProductVariation {Id = 1, ProductId = 1, VariantName = "Minivan"},
                new ProductVariation {Id = 2, ProductId = 1, VariantName = "Convertible"},
                new ProductVariation {Id = 3, ProductId = 2, VariantName = "Public Transportation"},
                new ProductVariation {Id = 4, ProductId = 2, VariantName = "Shuttle"});
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var products = (from p in context.Products
                join v in
                    context.ProductVariations on p.Id equals v.ProductId
                    into g
                from v in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new {product = p, variation = v})
                .AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(g => g.product, g => g.variation)
                .Select(g => new ProductwithVarientsGroupDto
                {
                    Label = g.Key.ProductName,
                    ProductId = g.Key.Id,
                    Items = g.Select(v => new ProdcutVariantsdto()
                    {
                        Label = g.Key.ProductName + (v == null
                            ? ""
                            : " (" + v.VariantName.ToString() + ")"),
                        ProductId = g.Key.Id,
                        ProdVariantId = v.Id > 0
                            ? v.Id
                            : 0
                    }).ToList()
                });

            var result = products.ToList();
            
            Debug.Assert(result.Count == 2);
            Debug.Assert(result[0].ProductId == 1);
            Debug.Assert(result[0].Items.Count == 2);
            Debug.Assert(result[0].Items[0].ProdVariantId == 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. If you want to read up about @PanagiotisKanavos comments concerning _joins_, see [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships). Especially also his point, not to use the generic repository pattern is very valid. A `DbSet<T>` already is a repository and `DbContext` already is a unit of work. For more information about that, see [Is the repository pattern useful with Entity Framework Core?](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/).